# Swagger API errors: reference could not be resolved

Tags: swagger

I'm trying to specify my API data types in swagger 2.0 using yaml, but I'm getting a reference error (see error details at the bottom).

I'm using a nested structure, where the parent object (InvoiceConfigData) contains an array of child objects (ProviderVariantsData). This is the hierarchy of yaml files:

.api/swagger/cfg/InvoiceConfigData.yaml:

```
required:
  - providerName
  - providerVariants
properties:    
  providerName:
    type: string
  providerVariants: 
    type: array                      
      items:      
        $ref: "#/definitions/ProviderVariantsData"
```

.api/swagger/cfg/ProviderVariantsData.yaml:

```
properties: 
  displayName:
    type: string
  cif:
    type: string
  availableTemplates:
    type: array
      items:
      type: string
```

.api/swagger/definitions.yaml:

```
ProviderVariantsData:
  $ref: ./cfg/ProviderVariantsData.yaml
InvoiceConfigData:
  $ref: ./cfg/InvoiceConfigData.yaml
```

But I get the following errors:

```
API Errors:

  #/definitions/InvoiceConfigData/$ref: Reference could not be resolved: ./cfg/InvoiceConfigData.yaml
  #/definitions/ProviderVariantsData/$ref: Reference could not be resolved: ./cfg/ProviderVariantsData.yaml

API Warnings:

  #/definitions/ProviderVariantsData: Definition is defined but is not used: #/definitions/ProviderVariantsData
```

There's something wrong in the way I reference the ProviderVariantsData, but I can't find what's causing the error. I've tried to flip the order in "definitions.yaml" (InvoiceConfigData above ProviderVariansData) without success.

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: The problem was the indentation in "items", it should be at the same level as "type".

Answer (score -2):

swagger 2.0 doesn't support multiple YAML files.

Comment: That seems false ? https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1534#issuecomment-363414736

Comment: Also I just did it :) so definitely false

Comment: @MathieuK. Can you please share an example of how you're able to use refs?